# Adding WPF Style Triggers and setters in sequence programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a style declared as shown:

```
<Style x:Key="NRunsBlockMetricsStyle" TargetType="syncfusion:GridCell">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},Path=Content.Text, Converter={StaticResource NRunsBMStyleConv}, ConverterParameter=BorderThickness}" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},Path=Content.Text}" Value=""/>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},Path=Content.Text}" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
        </MultiDataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>                
</Style>
```

I'm trying to create a new style in code behind based on this:

```
Style BlockActualStyle = new Style(typeof(GridCell), (Style)ctrl.FindResource("NRunsBlockMetricsStyle"));

BlockActualStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(GridCell.BackgroundProperty, useBrush));

TriggerBase MultiTrigger = BlockActualStyle.BasedOn.Triggers[0];

BlockActualStyle.Triggers.Add(MultiTrigger);
```

Basically, I'm trying to get the style, Add a default background colour, and then copy and re-add the Multidatatrigger so it will change the backgroundcolour if necessary. If I was to do this in XAML, it would work ok, as the initial setter is before the trigger. As I'm having to do this bit in code, I've found it doesn't work, most likely due to the trigger being run before the setter somehow. How do I make sure the default setter is performed before the trigger?

Rob